# No subset of a basis can be a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We are given that $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{V}$ so that span $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{V}$. I want to show that the following are equivalent:

1. $\mathcal{F}$ is a basis
2. No subset of $\mathcal{F}$ (apart from $\mathcal{F}$) is a basis

I have some ideas about showing $1 \implies 2$: consider some subset of a basis. Assume that it also spans the set. Now the elements of the subset of the basis are Linearly Independent. Write down the equation for this. Now write down the Linear Independence equation for the basis. Substituting the first in the second, we get that there are some elements of the basis that are not L.I, thus, it cannot be a basis. Is this reasoning correct? For the terms to cancel out, I need the coefficients for them to be the same which may not necessarily be the case?

About $2 \implies 1$, I'm not even sure how to start. How does no subset of a set in a given vector space being a basis relate to the set itself being a basis for that space?

Comment: What definition of basis are you using? The maximally independent set or the minimally spanning set? I might miss something, but your task could be equivalent or similar to showing the equivalence of these properties (in finite dimension).

Comment: For $1\implies 2$, Consider $\mathcal F \ni v \notin \{b_i\} \subsetneq \mathcal F$. Then write $v=\sum c_ib_i$. We have $S = \{b_i\}\cup\{v\} \subset \mathcal F$, but $S$ is linearly dependent by construction, so then is $\mathcal F$.

Comment: That $2\implies 1$ for infinite dimensional spaces may require the Axiom of Choice. The statement "every spanning set contains a basis" is in fact equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. Using Zorn's Lemma, consider the subsets $X$ of $\mathcal{F}$ that are linearly independent; partially order them by inclusion; use Zorn's Lemma to obtain a maximal $X_0$ having this property. Show that this means that $X_0$ spans $V$. Use 2 to conclude that $X_0=\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have not come across the multiple definitions, but all I am using is: Basis = a set of vectors that spans the vector space and is linearly independent.

Comment: @DavidP I didn't follow why $v \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin By "having this property", do you mean the maximal element $X_0$ that spans $\mathcal{V}$?

Comment: No. The property is "are linearly independent". So you want an element that is maximal among subsets of $\mathcal{F}$ that are linearly independent. You will then *prove* that this maximality *implies* it spans $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: Supposing that the maximal linearly independent subset $X_0$ of $\mathcal{F}$ does not span $\mathcal{V}$, then there must be some vectors that can be added to $X_0$ to obtain $X_1$ such that $X_0 \subset X_1$  and $X_1$ spans $\mathcal{V}$. But now, since $X_1 \subset \mathcal{F}$ and $X_0 \subset X_1$, $X_0$ cannot be the maximal linearly independent set. Is that reasoning correct? I think I understood your argument but I'm a little inexperienced with writing proofs rigorously. (For e.g., "adding vectors to the subset" above can be stated more precisely)

Comment: @mathenjoyer:  You want to be a bit more careful to construct $X_1$ (to ensure it remains a subset of $\mathcal{F}$), but the idea is right. If $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathrm{span}(X_0)$, then $V=\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{F})\subseteq \mathrm{span}(X_0)\subseteq V$, so $X_0$ spans $V$. Otherwise, there is a $v\in\mathcal{F}\setminus X_0$ which is not in $\mathrm{span}(X_0)$;  let $X_1=X_0\cup\{v\}$. Then this is linearly independent... etc.

Answer (score 1):

For $(2) \implies (1)$ consider the following proof if $V$ is finite dimensional:

Suppose $\mathcal F$ is not a basis for $V$. Since $\mathcal F$ spans $V$, $\mathcal F$ can be reduced to a basis $\mathcal B$ of $V$. Note that $\mathcal B$ is a proper subset of $\mathcal F$ (because $\mathcal F$ is not a basis by supposition) and a basis for $V$, which is impossible by assumption of $(2)$. Hence, $\mathcal F$ is a basis for $V$.